# C socket() problem

Tags: android, c

I have a big question. There are an application, which contain the following method:
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
The socket return 29 and I don't see the port in the terminal (netstat).

I use this method in Android-ndk and I use the INTERNET permission in the Android Manifest file.

What is the problem in the method?

Thanks

Comment: Others have pointed out the specific problem, but do yourself a big favor and write a wrapping executable and makefile so that you can also build your essential native code for a desktop linux or cygwin as this will make testing your networking issues a lot easier and faster.  If you'd started with generic socket networking code tested on the desktop, you wouldn't be having this problem and you wouldn't have been limited to android resources in researching it.

Answer (score 4):

29 is the socket number, you will use that in your calls to other socket-API functions (bind, connect, etc).

You don't see it in netstat because you haven't bound it to anything yet. In order for it to show up there, call `connect` or `bind`, `accept`, `listen` (depending on what you plan to do with it).

Answer (score 1):

The return code from `socket()` is just the file descriptor, not the port number. If your intention is to create a server, then you need to call `listen()`, `bind()`, and `accept()`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should `bind()`, `listen()` and `accept()` (if this is a server) or `connect()` (if client) before you can see it in netstat.

BTW, use `netstat -a` to see bound but non-connected sockets.